# Group By problem - need to get most recent rows for unique column combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table structure (in SQL Server) looks something like this: (D1 is more recent than D2, PK is a normal `Identity(1,1)` column)

```
Name  Type  Score  Date
A1    B1    C1     D1
A1    B2    C2     D1
A1    B1    C3     D2
```

What I need to do is find the latest `Score` values for each unique combination of `Name` and `Type`, i.e.:

```
A1    B1    C1     D1
A1    B2    C2     D1
```

I had originally done this by just using yesterday's date, but not everything is updated daily so sometimes scores were missing.
I can get the unique combinations I need to look at with a simple

```
SELECT Name, Type FROM Table GROUP BY Name, Type ORDER BY MAX(Date)
```

but I obviously can't add the other two columns or the groups are no longer unique.

I've had a look at similar questions but they all have differences that make them less useful for me.

Any help is much appreciated. I have a feeling that it's a *fairly* simple problem and that I just don't know enough to figure it out!

Comment: Which SQL server are you using is it mysql,postresql, oracle, microsoft SQL?....

Comment: Is there a PK col on the table?

Comment: @Bob thanks for the suggestions, I've added clarification

Comment: @BonyT same as above, could only tag one person per comment!

Comment: `name` cannot be the PK with this data.

Comment: `name` is not the real column name

Comment: Still, the column that is not named `Name` cannot be Primary Key, not with the data you posted.

Comment: @ypercube, you're absolutely right, I'm an idiot heh! It's the PK from another table so I got confused :/ This table has a normal identity(1,1) PK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT s.Name, s.Type, s.Score
FROM (
    SELECT Name, Type, MAX(Date) AS MaxDate
    FROM Scores
    GROUP BY Name, Type
) m
INNER JOIN Scores s ON m.Name = s.Name AND m.Type = s.Type AND m.MaxDate = s.Date
```

Comment: this also works great. Any advantages to this over @a_horse_with_no_name 's approach, or vice versa? This one does actually seem a little simpler to understand.

Comment: An advantage is that this can run in older versions (or other RDBMS like MySQL) that don't have analytic functions.

Comment: And a small difference is that if for a `(name,type)` combination there are two or more records with same maximum `date`, this query will return all those records while a_horse_with_no_name's will return only one record.

Answer (score 2):

Standard (ANSI) SQL solution:

```
SELECT name,
       type, 
       score,
       Date,
FROM ( 
   SELECT name,
          type, 
          score,
          Date,
          row_number() over (partition by name, type order by Date desc) as rn
   FROM your_table
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Depending on your DBMS you might need to quote the column names "Type" and "Date" as they are reserved words.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name perfect, this is exactly what I needed. I'm not exactly sure how it works, though, so I'll look up `partition` and `over` :) The column names are just aliases for clarity btw, but thanks.

Comment: @Alex: you might want to test marc's answer as well to check which one performs better.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yep, I'll run a couple of tests and I may have to switch accepted answers as his is a little easier on the eyes (and possibly the db!)

Comment: @Alex: An index on `(Name, Type, Date)` would benefit both versions.

Comment: @ypercube yeah, I've indexed things a bit better and it's much faster, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the best way to achieve this would be with a self-join, if it has to be Database-agnostic.

```
SELECT name, type, date, t2.score
  FROM (SELECT   name, type, MAX (date) date
            FROM  testdata
        GROUP BY name, type) t1
       JOIN
       testdata t2 USING (name, type, date)
```

Comment: @marc posted the same solution a few minutes ago.

Comment: Couldn't get this to work on SQL Server - `Incorrect syntax near 'USING'.` Apologies for not including the right tag in the first place!